# Want to write simple program to compare excel CSV's. Outputting to another CSV. Is Java or C++ recommended?

Tags: csv, comparison

as the title suggests, I am trying to determine which language would better suit for the task at hand.  I am probably going to include a GUI for the program.  Am I okay to proceed with Java for this task or is another language recommended?  Thanks

Comment: [primarily opinion-based](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) - Both Java and C++ are capable of doing pretty much anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak on the pros or cons of writing such a program in C++. However, Java seems well suited to accomplish your task.